# send an email using a template - grails

Tags: email, grails, groovy

I want to send an email using a template. I want to have a GSP file where i could style it, and send the email. Currently the send mail function is as follows:

```
def sendEmail(){

    mailService.sendMail {
        to "email","**email**"
        from "email"
        subject "Hi"
        body 'Hi'
    }
}
```

in my `config.groovy` file

```
grails {
    mail {
      host = "smtp.gmail.com"
      port = 465
      username = "email"
      password = "pwd"
      props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
 }
```

I went through another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445785/send-an-image-in-an-email-with-grails) on this: Where should i add the mail templates ? is it in the views folder ?

```
sendMail{
    multipart true
    to "[hidden email]"
    subject "Subject goes here"
    html  g.render( template: '/emails/mailTemplate')
    inline 'springsourceInlineImage', 'image/jpg', new File('./web-app/images/springsource.png')
}
```

UPDATE

I TREID ADDING A mailTemplate.gsp UNDER *EMAILS/* BUT IT DIDNT WORK.

ERROR I GOT Template not found for name [/emails/mailTemplate] and path [/emails/_mailTemplate.gsp]

Comment: under `views/emails/_mailTemplate.gsp`

Comment: Please mark @Abincepto's answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use groovyPageRenderer.render() to parse your email. Below, an example:

```
class MailingService {

    def groovyPageRenderer
    def mailService

    def yourFunction(User user) {

        def content = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: '/mails/myTemplate')
        mailService.sendMail {
            to user.email
            from "email@test.com"
            subject "MySubject"
            html(content)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the template is here: /views/mails/MyTemplateFile.gsp

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** 
And the render could be used with a model. Example:

```
groovyPageRenderer.render(view:'/mails/myTemplate',model:[user:user])
```

**Edit2:** 
I forgot to add the mailService in my first reply

Comment: i get this error "Cannot invoke method render() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method render() on null object"

Comment: Did you add the second line of my answer "def groovyPageRenderer" ?

Comment: I have included that line. But still i get the error `Cannot invoke method render() on null object`

Comment: May be you need to add this import: "import grails.gsp.PageRenderer" and define the renderer as "PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer". I tried the code using Grails 2.3.7 and it works. I hope your code will work with these modifications.

Comment: Please Note. I have added the code in the `Services` section.

Comment: My code also lives in a service. GroovyPageRenderer is in the documentation and the example is about mail rendering (http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/single.html#webFeatures). I will try later using 2.2.4

Answer (score 6):

well, you can try this code...

```
mailService.sendMail {
            to user.email
            from "email@test.com"
            subject "MySubject"
            body(view:'/emails/mailTemplate', model: [a:A])
        }
```

here `mailTemplate.gsp` is in `view/emails`. In body of mail service you can use render syntax.
then add `'<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>'` in top of `mailTemplate.gsp`

Comment: Throws exception `Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mail views cannot be loaded from relative view paths where there is no current HTTP request [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mail views cannot be loaded from relative view paths where there is no current HTTP request]`

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at your code, everything looks good enough.

```
html g.render(template : '/path/to/template')
```

should render your template and it will become the body of your mail message.

Have you made sure that you made your template as `_template`. Since all the gsp's that start with `(_)` are only considered as a template.

You should also make all the styling(css) inline so that it gets rendered without errors in all mail providers.