# Email Sending Python to Java Conversion

Tags: java, python, grails, base64, html-email

I have base64 encoded image stored in the database. I want to generate emails with this base64 image as inline image within the body. 
I tried sending the image as

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAooA....'/>
```

But my receiving email server is considering email body with base64 content as spam. But I was able to solve this issue in python. The code used for the same is

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = Header(u'Subject', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msg_alternative)

data = 'Hi, <img src="cid:imageId" alt="alternate text"><br><br>'
decodedImage = base64.b64decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAooA....")
msg_image = MIMEImage(decodedImage, name="image")
msg_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<imageId>')
msg_image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline')
msg.attach(msg_image)
```

Using the above code, i was able to deliver the email with inline image successfully using sendmail module in python.

But what I want was to achieve the same using grails email plugin.
And this stack overflow URL helped me to start with.
[Send an image in an email with Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445785/send-an-image-in-an-email-with-grails)

But I went somewhere wrong. The code I used is given below.

```
String base64String = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAooA....";
byte[] byteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(base64String.getBytes());
String decodedString = new String(byteArray);

String htmlStr = 'Hi, <img src="cid:imageId" alt="alternate text"><br><br>';

    sendMail {
    from "sender@somedomain.com"
    to "receiver@somedomain.com"
    subject "Report - Sample"
    html htmlStr
    inline 'imageId', 'image/png', decodedString
    }
```

But it is showing some errors like "No matching property inline..".
But I think the problem is with the paramater value decodedString with the inline property.

Note: The base64 image string I used is not a complete one.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note here, `multipart` has to be set to `true` and `inline` image should take `byte[]` or `File` or `InputStreamSource` as the last param :

```
sendMail {
    multipart true //has to be there as first line

    from "sender@somedomain.com"
    to "receiver@somedomain.com"
    subject "Report - Sample"
    html htmlStr

    //Use raw byte array instead of string
    inline 'imageId', 'image/png', byteArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to plugins source code there are possible `inline()` invocations:

```
inline(String fileName, String contentType, byte[] bytes)
inline(File file)
inline(String fileName, File file)
inline(String fileName, String contentType, File file)
inline(String fileName, String contentType, InputStreamSource source)
```

So you should pass your `byteArray` (not the `String` based on it) to match the first one:

```
sendMail {
    from "sender@somedomain.com"
    to "receiver@somedomain.com"
    subject "Report - Sample"
    html htmlStr
    inline 'imageId', 'image/png', byteArray
}
```